# How does the C++ begin and end work when argument is an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, stl

A problem in C++ primer, when begin and end work on vector I know there is vector::size() could help, but how do they work when I just give an array argument.
just like:

```
int arr[] = {1, 2, 3};
size = end(arr) - begin(arr);
```

how do end(arr) and begin(arr) work correctly ?

Comment: Did you mean `int arr[]` ?

Comment: [How does std::end know the end of an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33496322/1708801) seems relevant if not a duplicate.

Comment: I suppose strictly speaking since this question asks about both begin and end it not a exact duplicate. Also @user1034749 question should be clarified as well.

Comment: @Shafik Yaghmour thank you, I couldn't find that question before...this is really a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So to see how [std::end](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) works we can look at [How does std::end know the end of an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33496322/1708801) and see that the signature for `std::end` is:

```
template< class T, std::size_t N >
T* end( T (&array)[N] );
```

and it is using template non-type parameter to deduce the size of the array and it is just a matter of pointer arithmetic to obtain the end:

```
return array + N ;
```

For `std::begin` the signature is identical, with the exception of the name:

```
template< class T, std::size_t N >
T* begin( T (&array)[N] );
```

and calculating the beginning of the array is simply a matter of [array to pointer decay](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/1708801) which gives us a pointer to the first element of the array.

In C++14 these both become constexpr.

Answer (score 2):

I'll just paste a piece of code from [here](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/iterator)

```
template <class _Tp, size_t _Np>
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR_AFTER_CXX11
_Tp*
begin(_Tp (&__array)[_Np])
{
    return __array;
}

template <class _Tp, size_t _Np>
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR_AFTER_CXX11
_Tp*
end(_Tp (&__array)[_Np])
{
    return __array + _Np;
}
```

Comment: This is an awful answer, it has no explanation.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour, isn't the code clear enough?

Comment: thank you very much, although I still don't know the "inline" in this piece of code....

Comment: @alexxx see http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/2LywvCM9/ for inline