# How to use sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[n])

Tags: c++, size

> To avoid things quietly breaking if you change the array size, I suggest `std::copy(a, a + sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]), b);`. Even better, wrap the `sizeof()` junk in a macro -- or even betterer, use a function template instead: `template <typename T, size_t N> size_t size((T&)[N]) { return N; }` – j_random_hacker Sep 8 '12 at 7:29

When i I was looking into Q&A this morning I found this comment(with 4 upvotes). I'm quite new at C++. What does `a+sizeof(a[0])` means here, I thought `sizeof(a[0])` will return 4 which stands for a int memory byte? Many thanks in advance!!.

Comment: "What does a+sizeof(a[0]) means here" maybe everything since it isn't used here.

Comment: You can find a good explanation of the function template solution in my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33496357/1708801)

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Thanks!

Comment: Note that you are **much** better off rather using `std::copy(std::begin(a), std::end(a), b)`! Aside from this notation actually being short it also guards against accidental misuses of `sizeof()`: if `a` happens to be a pointer using `std::begin(a)` or `std::end(a)` will result in an error while the version using `sizeof(a)` happily compiles producing wrong results!

Comment: @DietmarKühl Oh thank you so much man! I will keep that in mind! I will try to use modern conventions and the prevailing methods(like using array,vector containers and string rather than using built-in array or char array). Those old-fashioned ones I will try to avoid using them!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would simple be:

```
sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])
```

doesn't matter which element you chose (*ie* `n` or `0`)

Comment: @Des1gnWizard Expression within `sizeof` is not evaluated, you can have `*a` instead of `a[0]` as well.

Comment: Yes, any element in the range (might just be to `n - 1`) will do as well as any other

Comment: @PaulEvans Sure:-) But I think there's a difference, when I cout sizeof(a) it gives me the total bytes while cout sizeof(a[n]) will give me the number of elements in the array correct?

Comment: @PaulEvans And it doesn't matter in the loop statement here because the compiler will change everything suitable for the program right?

Comment: No, only `sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])` will give you the correct number of elements for *any* array `a`.  Only in the case of `sizeof(a[0]) == 1` is the size correct (*ie* the size of `char a[N]` equals `sizeof(a)`

Comment: @PaulEvans Sorry Paul, one last question. Normally we all represent it like a+4 or &a[0] +4 to stand for the address of the 5th element(or off-the-end), here 4 is the sizeof(a[n]), but it is also valid to use a+sizeof(a) which add bytes? So basically there is no difference adding "number of elements" and "number of bytes" here? Thank you!

Comment: Just use plain numbers.  The compiler *knows* that `a + 4` means `&a[0] + 4 * sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])`.  The compiler is also just as happy with `*(a + 4)` as it is with `a[4]` for *any* array `a`

Comment: @PaulEvans K I will just use plain number then!

Answer (score 0):

If `a` is an array then `sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])` is the amount of elements in `a`. It is the size of whole array per size of one element.

So if `a` is a an array, then `a + sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])` is a pointer to right after the end of the array.

Comment: If `a` is a pointer, then `a + sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])` is *not* a pointer right after the end of the array. That only works if `a` is an array. That's why it's better to use something like `std::end(a)`, which will actually give you a compile time error if you pass it a pointer.