# How to indicate the array length to the c++ compiler

Tags: c++, g++, vectorization, simd, auto-vectorization

A common reason why code involving character sequences aren't vectorized is demonstrated by the following example. `find_a()` is a toy function that sets the `current_index` pointer to the next occurring `'a'`:

```cpp
    void find_a(size_t *current_index, const std::string &code) {
        const size_t code_size = code.size();
        size_t       ci        = *current_index;
        while (ci < code_size && code[ci] != 'a') { ci++; }
        *current_index = ci;
    }

    void find_a_vectorize(size_t *current_index, const std::string &code) {
        const size_t code_size = code.size();
        size_t       ci        = *current_index;
    
        while (ci < (code_size-128)) { 
            char cpy[128];
            std::memcpy(cpy, &code[ci], 128);
            bool found = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++) {
                if (cpy[i] == 'a') {found = true;}
            }
            if (found){
                break;
            }
            ci+=128;
        }
        while (ci < code_size && code[ci] != 'a') { ci++; }
        *current_index = ci;
    }
```

The reason you have to write the second version for auto-vectorizing is, because the compiler doesn't know the length of the array (inside of the string). Vectorizing may read past the end of the array. Thus all loops with an early `break` or `return` can't be vectorized with a detrimental impact to performance. I don't think I need to explain why the second version is objectively worse.

I scavenged the web for a solution, and even asked ChatGPT (he recommended solving it with `__restrict, smart`). I'm looking for something like `__builtin_guaranteed_minimal_array_length(&code[0], code_size)`. Since it is only a hint, a solution for just clang would be sufficient. Is there a way?

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/ojEc8rnen

Comment: How would you use your hypotetical `__builtin_guaranteed_minimal_array_length()` to aid vectorization? The main issue for auto-vectorization is not the array length, it's the fact that you would need to break out in any case when you find `'a'`. The compiler should already be able to cope with short lengths or lengths that are not exact multiples of the vector length.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I'm not sure what a good interface would be, my main hope is, that the compiler generates the assembly of the second version. I provided a godbolt link to demonstrate that. It takes one instruction to check if at least one byte in a sequence of 64 bytes contains an 'a'. If any of the 64 bytes contains an 'a', you search with an finer granularity. Otherwise you can skip a lot of bytes. I didn't unit test both versions but they should do the exact same thing.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: The OP is hoping for a vectorized check in chunks of 128 bytes by writing it as a reduction over that many bytes.  So the inner loop that sets `found` could vectorize. Since they don't need the position from that loop, just present/absent, a compiler might do something not horrible. (If they did try to produce `i` from that, instead of doing the scalar search later, a compiler would probably widen to 32 or 64-bit elements and blend to reduce or something horrible, if it vectorized at all.  They probably don't know x86 `pcmpeqb` / `pmovmskb` / `tzcnt` like libc `memchr` will use)

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: Oh, I see now, they're hoping that by just telling the compiler the length in the **first** version, it could then auto-vectorize.  As you say, that's not correct; the compiler needs the loop trip-count to be exactly computable before the first iteration, not just an upper bound, so the early-out branch is a showstopper.

Comment: It seems your second version doesn't need to do that copy thing to achieve vectorization. Instead of your `if (cpy[i] == 'a') {found = true;}`, just do `if (code[ci+i] == 'a') {found = true;}`.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks for putting my observation in much better terms, yes, that is what I was trying to say. Seems like OP's answer is: nope, not possible.

Comment: My answer on [Auto vectorization with Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73118583) goes into that limitation of auto-vectorization in LLVM (and GCC) optimizers.  As https://godbolt.org/z/bTcTsf8Mn shows, auto-vectorization happens for `a[i] += b[i]` with a completely unknown length, GCC just checks it and jumps to the cleanup (which conditionally does one half-width vector, then scalar).

Comment: Even something like C11 `void func(char foo[static 32])` to promise that the whole size definitely exists doesn't help a loop with an early-out.  (That syntax might only work with a constant, not another variable, not sure.  And it's not a lower bound, it's an exact size.)  C++ lacks that `static` syntax; [If arrays are passed by reference why should i use int(&)\[\]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77050413) shows how C++ can pass array size info.

Comment: @PeterCordes So basically what I hear is, that a lower bound for the size isn't helpful because the current auto-vectorizers only vectorize when given an exact trip count. But my problem is, that this is in theory not necessary (and it complicates my C++ code). So I should make a feature request with the compiler devs?

Comment: I'd expect there's already one open for this limitation; check GCC's bugzilla and LLVM's github issue tracker.  Intel's ICC is actually able to vectorize loops with an early-out, but none of the other mainstream x86 compilers can. :/  Hand-written asm in library implementations of `memchr` and `strchr` are also vectorized, so it's well known that vectorization is possible, and on x86 highly profitable even when the loop termination condition depends directly on the data.  I'd assume this isn't something compiler devs "forgot" or weren't aware was a problem, and would require a big redesign.

Comment: Indicating the array length alone does not help, e.g. `size_t pos = 32; for(long i=pos; i-->0; pos = (str[i]=='a') ? i : pos);` could (should) be compiled to a `vpcmpeqb`, `vpmovmskb` and a `tzcnt`, but it does not: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Kz5Kn6vYY